# Prove that if $A\subseteq B$, and $A$ is uncountable, then $B$ is uncountable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

"Prove that if $A\subseteq B$, and $A$ is uncountable, then $B$ is uncountable"

I think that for an answer we could reason with cardinality as follows
Suppose that $B$ is countable, then $\mid B\mid\leq\mid\mathbb{N\mid} $.

But if $A\subseteq B$, then $|A|\leq|B|\leq|\mathbb{N\mid}$ that is untrue if $A$ is uncountable, since any uncountable set should have higher cardinality then natural numbers.

Is it correct?

Comment: You could have concluded this in lots of better ways than to assume $A$ is uncountable in the end, e.g "...then $|A|\leq |B|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$, so the result follows by transitivity of the order $\leq$".

Answer (score 1):

$A\subseteq B$

Then the inclusion map $I :A \to B$ defined by  $I(a) =a $ for all $a\in A $ is an one-to-one map.

Hence, $card(A) \le card(B) $

Given, $A$ is uncountable i.e $\aleph_{0} < card(A) $

Hence, $\aleph_{0} < card(A)\le card(B) $

So, $\aleph_{0} < card(B) $ implies $B$ is also uncountable.

Note: $\aleph_{0} = card (\mathbb{N})$

Answer (score 0):

Right, starting from "Suppose (for contradiction) that $B$ is countable" is a good start.  Now what do we mean by "countable"?  Perhaps this means $|B|\le |\Bbb N|$, it depends on the definitions that your class uses, but then what does THAT mean?

One way or another, I think the best place to get to from here, is the fact that there exists an injective (a.k.a. "one-to-one") function $f:B\to\Bbb N$.  From here, can you build an injective function $A\to \Bbb N$?  If so, this would mean $A$ is countable, and there's your contradiction.

(Note: all of what you wrote is basically right, but without talking about injective functions, it may not be adequately rigorous.)